# C++ ostream implicitly deleted with template

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I have a templated class that I am trying to print out using operator << but get the errors:

```
Vertex.h:24:16: error: use of deleted function 'std::basic_ostream<char>::basic_ostream(const std::basic_ostream<char>&)'
```

where line 24 refers to the return of the output operator in the following code:

```
/In declaration of templated class Vertex
friend std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream& ost, const Vertex<T>& v) {
    ost << v.getItem();
    return ost;
}

//In main function
Vertex<int>* v1 = new Vertex<int>();
v1->setItem(15);
cout << *v1 << endl;
```

How can I get this output working?

Comment: since you are passing ostream by reference, return it by reference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`std::ostream` and siblings doesn't have [copy constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/basic_ostream) and [copy assignment operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator%3D)<sup>[1]</sup>, and when you made the following possibly typoed code

```
std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream& ost, const Vertex<T>& v) {
// ^ Returning by value
    ost << v.getItem();
    return ost;
}
```

you are actually trying to return a copy of `ost`. To fix that, you must return the stream by reference.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ost, const Vertex<T>& v) {
//          ^ This
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> In C++11, they are actually marked as `=delete`d